# how to know when the next/previous page has completely loaded in the page curl effect by harism?

Tags: android, animation, curl, textview, page-curl

I have implemented [Page Curl Effect by harism](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) in my application.

Now I need to do some text animation on top of the pages. I am able to put the text over the pages and also able to animate. However, I need to know when the curl effect has completed and next/previous page has completely loaded, as I need to make the TextView invisible and stop the animation when the page curl effect is in process.

I have been struggling to find when the page is completely loaded/page curl animation has finished. I have also posted my question on github harism repository in the issues section and [android-developers forum on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/android-developers/DWCHcL7Vwfk), but have not received any replies. Hope to get some help out here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is method **onDrawFrame** in CurlView class. There you can see that parts of code where you can determine if page has been completely loaded:

```
 if (mCurlState == CURL_LEFT) {
         --mCurrentIndex;
// left curl has been completely loaded
//here you can add some code 
    }
```

and 
if it is right page curl

```
 if (mCurlState == CURL_RIGHT) {
     ++mCurrentIndex;
// right curl has been completely loaded
//here you can add some code 
    }
```