# How to know index of current page page curl project by Harism?

Tags: android, page-curl

I'm creating **e-book reader** app using page curl by harism.Problem is when you are curling pages, there are *three bitmap pages* and I can not figure out how to know at which index I am.For example if I am curling to right there are 4,5 pages drawn.If I move to page which index is 5, that time fourth page was not cleared yet.If I move back to page 4 bitmap will draw third page and it only opens previous page, not draws.Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where and when you want to fetch the current page index.

But, I just went through the code of Harism. When you are in a transition phase you will always be confused which page it is. Because it is trying to show content of both the previous and the next page.

So better wait till the page curling is finished and then fetch the current page index for your operation.

Comment: how to know when page curling is finished?

Comment: Get the answer by Harism himself from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841954/android-page-curl-animation-by-harism-shows-inconsistency-in-the-reverse-index-c?rq=1)

Comment: I did not get the answer I'm trying to find, but I would like to give bounties to you for your effort

Comment: Nowhere it's mentioned........ @TabrejKhan,"how to know when page curling is finished?- Get the answer by Harism himself from here......."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849143/how-to-know-when-the-next-previous-page-has-completely-loaded-in-the-page-curl-e/22127932#22127932

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify the SizeChangedObserver class it will display only one page at a time

private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
        public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {

```
        mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
        mCurlView.setMargins(.0f, .0f, .0f, .0f);

}
```

}

mCurlView.getCurrentIndex() will return a position of your selected page